# web client software factory in Asp .net

Tags: wcsf

What is the WCSF(web client software factory).
what is the use of it.
what is the relation between MVP with it.

please let me know about this in simple manner.

Answer (score 0):

WCSF is a MVP implementation by Microsoft, based on ASP.NET and Visual Studio "Guidance Packages", that help you structure your application tiers in a way dictated by the MVP paradigm, while fulfilling another architectural requirement - composite application consisting of loosely-coupled components. Builds on top of Enterprise Library.

Benefits of using WCSF:

- Well defined (somewhat enforced) separation between UI and "back end"    logic (the MVP pattern).
- Framework that allows for integration of components developed    separately (usually by different teams and/or in different point in    time)
- Framework consisting of loosely-coupled components, allowing painless    re-implementation of existing components from any tier of the    application
- Software development process structure and Architectural structure    imposed by the framework and the Visual Studio Guidance Packages.